# Trying to get Box2D bodies to fall [SFML, Box2D, C++]

Tags: c++, physics, box2d, sfml

As the title says I'm trying to make my Box2D body to fall, but it won't work.
It just stays at the same position.

Sorry for the long codes but I have no idea where I'm doing something wrong, so I have to grab it all.

---

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp> // Always use / instead of \ since \ is windows only!
#include <string>
#include <Box2D/Box2D.h>
#include <vector>

#include "World.h"
#include "Box.h"

sf::RenderWindow window;
sf::Font font;
sf::Clock;

// Window variables
int WIDTH = 1024;
int HEIGHT = 720;

sf::Clock timeBetweenFrames;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    World world = World();
    world.Init();

    Box box = Box(*world.world, sf::Color(255, 0, 0, 255), 30, 30, 30, 30, true);

    // Creating and initialization of the world.

    // Limiting the framerate so Box2D will work properly.
    window.setFramerateLimit(60);

    // Initializing font.
    std::cout << "Loading..." << std::endl;

    if (!font.loadFromFile("Res/Fonts/arial.ttf"))
        std::cout << "Could not load font : arial.ttf" << std::endl;

    // Creating a text
    sf::Text text("I am text, not bread.", font, 15);

    // Creating and initializing the window.
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT), "SFML Engine");


    std::cout << "Loading done" << std::endl;

    // Game Loop
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        box.Update();
        world.world->Step(1 / 60, 8, 3);

        sf::Time time = timeBetweenFrames.getElapsedTime();
        std::cout << (time.asSeconds()) << std::endl;

        timeBetweenFrames.restart().asSeconds();

        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {

            switch (event.type)
            {

            case sf::Event::Closed:
                window.close();
                break;

            }
        }

        if (window.hasFocus())
        {
            if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A))
            {
                //player.move(-1, 0);
            }

            if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::D))
            {
                //player.move(1, 0);
            }

            if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::W))
            {
                //player.move(0, -1);
            }

            if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::S))
            {
                //player.move(0, 1);
            }

        }


        // Drawing
        window.draw(text);
        window.draw(box.GetBox());

        window.display();
        window.clear();

    }

}
```

**World.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <Box2D\Box2D.h>

class World
{
public:
    World();
    ~World();


    b2World* world;
    void Init();

private:
    bool doSleep = true;
    b2Vec2 gravity; //9.81 is earth gravity.
};

World.cpp
#include "World.h"

/// Initializes the new world
World::World()
{

}

void World::Init()
{
    b2Vec2 gravity(0, -9.81f);
    world = new b2World(gravity, doSleep);
}

/// Destructor, nothing here yet
World::~World()
{
}
```

**Box.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "Box2D\Box2D.h"
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>

class Box
{
public:
    Box(b2World& world, sf::Color color, float posX, float posY, float sizeX, float sizeY, bool dynamic);
    ~Box();

    b2Body GetBody();
    sf::RectangleShape GetBox();

    void Update();

private:
    sf::RectangleShape box;

    b2Body* body;
    b2BodyDef bodyDef;
    b2PolygonShape bodyShape;
    b2FixtureDef bodyFix;

};
```

**Box.cpp**

```
#include "Box.h"
#include "World.h"

#define MTP 30 // 1 box2d meter should be 30 pixels.

Box::Box(b2World& world, sf::Color color, float posX, float posY, float sizeX, float sizeY, bool dynamic)
{
    box.setFillColor(color);
    box.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(posX, posY));
    box.setSize(sf::Vector2f(sizeX, sizeY));

    bodyDef.position.Set(1, 1);

    if (dynamic == true)
        bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    else if (dynamic == false)
        bodyDef.type = b2_staticBody;

    bodyShape.SetAsBox(1, 1);
    bodyFix.shape = &bodyShape;
    bodyFix.density = 1.0f;
    bodyFix.friction = 1.0f;

    body = world.CreateBody(&bodyDef);
    body->CreateFixture(&bodyFix);
}

void Box::Update()
{
    box.setRotation(body->GetAngle());
    box.setPosition(body->GetPosition().x / MTP, body->GetPosition().y / MTP);
}

sf::RectangleShape Box::GetBox()
{
    return  box;
}

Box::~Box()
{
}
```

Comment: Print out Box's `body->GetPosition()` to check if you have some problems in setup/linking to Box2D

Comment: @RomanHudylko Don't think that's the problem, making a box fall has worked before, however it was in a main.cpp file only.

Comment: @RomanHudylko It returns 1 on both X and Y.

Comment: You should check if the value changes on each frame

Comment: @RomanHudylko I do, each frame. Always print 1 on both x and y axis. So the body isn't moving either... :/

Comment: So you got the problem: the body isn't moving. Some problem in Box2D setup or in body/world creation. I'm not sure but maybe you are messing up when you are dereferencing the world when passing it to the Box constructor, try using always a pointer. Also what program do you use to develop everything?

Comment: @RomanHudylko If you mean my IDE, I use Visual Studio 2015 Community. Since the body could fall before (in the same project) I'm 99% sure it's not a problem with the setup, i'll try to play around with the world as you said though.

Comment: Wait, isn't this pretty much exactly [the question you asked yesterday](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/112929/7804) that I answered? Please don't post duplicates.

Comment: @Anko You're right, its a duplicate. Though when I created the other question I thought it was another problem (not sure why.... lol)