# Why do my Box2D bodies not fall, even though world.step is called?

Tags: c++, physics, box2d, sfml

I have SFML set up with a Box2D world that has gravity, but my bodies won't
move.  I `std::cout`'ed the position of the body in the game loop, but it's always at `(0, 14)`!

No errors or warnings, just no movement when there's supposed to be.

I'm quite new to Box2D, so I'm unsure if I'm doing this correctly. What mistake am I making?

**main.cpp**:

```
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
#include <Box2D\Box2D.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include "Box.h"

sf::RenderWindow window;


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Initialize stuff here since the things here will only run on startup
    b2Vec2 gravity(0, 9.8f);
    b2World world = b2World(gravity, true);

    // Initialize entities
    b2BodyDef groundBodyDef;
    groundBodyDef.position.Set(0.0f, -10.0f);
    b2Body* groundBody = world.CreateBody(&groundBodyDef);

    b2PolygonShape groundBox;
    groundBox.SetAsBox(50.0f, 10.0f);
    groundBody->CreateFixture(&groundBox, 0.0f);

    Box box;
    box.init(&world, sf::Vector2f(0.0f, 14.0f), sf::Vector2f(15.0f, 15.0f), sf::Color::White);

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1200, 840), "Title");

    while (window.isOpen())
    {

        sf::Event e;
        while (window.pollEvent(e))
        {

            if (e.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();

        }


        // Drawing

        world.Step(1 / 60, 8, 3);

        window.clear();


        box.getSfShape().setPosition(sf::Vector2f(box.getBody()->GetPosition().x / 30.0f, box.getBody()->GetPosition().y / 30.0f));
        box.getSfShape().setRotation(box.getBody()->GetAngle());

        window.draw(box.getSfShape());

        //std::cout << "X : " << box.getSfShape().getPosition().x << " Y : " << box.getSfShape().getPosition().y << std::endl;
        std::cout << "X : " << box.getBody()->GetPosition().x << " Y : " << box.getBody()->GetPosition().y << std::endl;

        window.display();

    }

}
```

**Box.h**:

```
#pragma once

#include <Box2D\Box2D.h>
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>

class Box
{

public:
    Box();
    ~Box();

    void init(b2World* world, sf::Vector2f position, sf::Vector2f dimensions, sf::Color color);

    b2Body* getBody() { return body; }
    b2Fixture* getFixture() { return fixture; }

    sf::RectangleShape getSfShape() { return sfmlShape; }

private:
    b2Body* body = nullptr;
    b2Fixture* fixture = nullptr;

    sf::RectangleShape sfmlShape;

};
```

**Box.cpp**:

```
#include "Box.h"



Box::Box()
{

}


Box::~Box()
{

}

void Box::init(b2World * world, sf::Vector2f position, sf::Vector2f dimensions, sf::Color color)
{
    // Creates a body definition
    b2BodyDef bodyDef;
    bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    bodyDef.position.Set(position.x, position.y);

    // Create the body into the world
    body = world->CreateBody(&bodyDef);

    // Create the box for the body
    b2PolygonShape boxShape;
    boxShape.SetAsBox(dimensions.x / 2.0f, dimensions.y / 2.0f);

    // Create a fixture for the body
    b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;
    fixtureDef.shape = &boxShape;
    fixtureDef.density = 1.0f;
    fixtureDef.friction = 0.3f;
    fixture = body->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);

    sfmlShape.setFillColor(color);
    sfmlShape.setPosition(body->GetPosition().x / 30.0f, body->GetPosition().y / 30.0f);
    sfmlShape.setRotation(body->GetAngle());
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`1/60` in your `world.Step` call is an [**integer division**, which truncates toward zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division-in-c). The world is being told to step by 0 seconds every iteration of the loop, hence nothing moves.

Write `1.0f / 60.0f` instead.

Comment: Ohhhh, thank you! Body is moving now! :) Though the sfmlShape is not. :/

Comment: I'm not sure if I should create a new post with my sfml shape not moving. Kinda new here, should I create a new post or just ask on this post?

Comment: @BiiX No problem, happy to help. :) Each separate issue should go in its own question, so I'd say ask a new one. Additional tips: With debugging questions, try to keep your example [as minimal as possible](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show your debugging efforts so far (printouts, stuff you've ruled out, etc). (Just in case your other problem is harder to "just see" based on the code.)